# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (7,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, rnn, lstm

Hi everybody can somebody help me!! I don't know what's wrong in my code and why it gives me this error ???[image]

[image]

Comment: Were you able to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2):

This normally appears in the `training.py/training_utils.py` file from the keras package.

I was having a problem when I was using the `LIME` package on a `keras` model. *(This is a work-in-progress, so the workaround mentioned here may not be the correct approach)*

It appears that the shape of the data file differs from the one that the module is expecting. I did a workaround by collapsing the shape of the data object to the one required. Seems to have worked.